# Derivatives of Sets

Tags: integration, derivatives

So, I often see this: $$D_x \left\lbrack \int f(x) \right\rbrack = f(x)$$
But this is a derivative of a set of antiderivatives. What is the conceptual backing for this i.e. what does it mean to derive a set?

Comment: Is it just the derivative of a fixed $f$ evaluated at $x$?

Comment: @simonzack derivative with respect to $x$

Comment: All of the functions in this set of functions have the same derivative. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy But you know there is a difference between a derivative of a function and a derivative of a set.

Comment: @SalmonKiller : I've never seen any definition of "derivative of a set" but I take this present notation to mean that every function in this set of functions has the same derivative.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Truthfully, you don't use indefinite integrals that much. You almost always will deal with an integral with limits of integration.

To expand on Robert's answer, the "derivative, $f(x)$ of a set, $S$" is the unique function such that for all $F(X) \in S$, $F'(x)=f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear enough: if $g$ is any antiderivative of $f$, then the derivative of $g$ is $f$.

Comment: But the indefinite integral is a set of antiderivatives.